# mySQL query doesnt work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have 2 tables in my database :

```
users
------
id
deviceID
os
pushToken
```

and

```
subscription
------
deviceID
pushToken
```

When a user needs to be subscribed in the subscription table , he **only** "gives" me his **deviceID**.
Then with this statement i add his **deviceID** and his **pushToken** to the table :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO subscription(deviceID,pushToken)
                        Select deviceID , pushToken FROM users  WHERE deviceID = :deviceID");
$stmt->execute(array(':deviceID' => $deviceID));
```

This works perfectly and i am able to get the pushToken from the users table and write it in the subscriptions table.

However later i noticed that i dont really want to have the **deviceID** in the subscription table. What i really need is to have the **os** . So the subscription table now looks like this:

```
subscription
------
os
pushToken
```

With the same *logic* as before , when the user passes me his **deviceID** i want to be able to subscribe him to this new table. I wrote this statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO subscription(os,pushToken)
                        Select os , pushToken FROM users  WHERE deviceID = :deviceID");
$stmt->execute(array(':deviceID' => $deviceID));
```

However this time , i cant get the *INSERT* work ! I also dont get an error..

What could be wrong here?

### EDIT

---

I started to understand where is the problem , i dont know how to fix it though. I am actually getting an error and the error is :

```
PDOException Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'deviceUDID' in 'where clause'
```

Why do i get it though?

All i want is to get the os and the pushToken from the user table WHERE the deviceID in this table is a specific one. How can i write this query?

Also would be nice to know why the query i wrote is wrong... It doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: Try changing `INSERT INTO $subscription` to `INSERT INTO subscription`: that dollar simbol shouldn't be there.

Comment: $subscription is actually a variable that contains the database name. Thats not the problem. I ll edit my answer though to avoid future confusion. thanks for the feedback

Comment: copy the query u wriiten here it will work before u r writing `deviceUDID` instead `deviceID` see the error carefulyy

Comment: If you already have the data in the users table, why do you need it anywhere else?  If you don't know what the term "normalized" means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviusly you get 0 rows because you are using the `os` parameter at where condition with deviceId `WHERE deviceID = :deviceID` you have to change the where column. I mean that you have to change it to `WHERE os = :deviceID`

**UPDATE**

Also, to avoid missunderstanding change `:deviceID` to `:os` if possible.

Comment: But i want to put in the subscription table the OS and the pushToken from the user table WHERE the deviceID is the given deviceID. do you understand? Eg. In the user table there is a user with deviceID 1 , os: android , pushToken: ABC . Give the deviceID 1 , i want to put in the subscription table the os: android and pushtoken: ABC . The os , is not unique so i cant use it like this. There are many many entries with the same os. I need to pass the os and pushToken of this unique entry with the unique deviceID

Comment: @donparalias I saw your update. The error is really specific. Your `devideUDID` is not defined as column at table `users`. Check that exists and it is called properly. You want to add at subscription `os` and `pushtoken` searching by `deviceID`, if I'm not wrong that's what you want. First I recommend you right now it's to check that if exists the columns that you want, with same properties in both tables.

Comment: But if you read my question you ll understand that of course it exists!!And of course it works perfectly fine with other queries! The problem is that the query "thinks" i am trying to use the "Where..." inside the subscriptions table! That is where the error is showing!!! And yes you understood well what i am trying! I must limit somehow the "Where..." only inside the users table.

Comment: Try specifying column names with his table name: `INSERT INTO subscription(os,pushToken) SELECT users.os , users.pushToken FROM users WHERE users.deviceID = :deviceID`. **EDIT** Also the error you posted says that column `deviceUDID` does not exist and you are saying that you use `deviceID`, but you said that columns exist and worked fine till now. Please let me know, to avoid that you are not wrong with your column names, etc., which is the column name that you are using.